# For Kicad, some pads seem to not be compatible with each other, is there a way to fix this?

Tags: kicad

[image]

I am a beginner at Kicad and I was working on a project where I need to get input from IR sensors. I am using an 11.1 V battery, so I need to use a voltage divider to make sure that there is not a voltage overload. However, when I try to route the middle of the voltage divider to the IR sensor, it does not go to the center of the pin, nor does it touch the pin. I have tried this with some other footprints and it does not seem that they are compatible. Is this a problem with the layers? I see that the route tracks are touching the outer circle, would this still be a problem, and if so, is there a way to make it work?

I tried it with other IR sensors, and the ones that had square-shaped pins were able to have the route tracks go to the center of them. Would changing the pads to square pads on the footprint work or would this not correspond with the IR sensor? I have not printed out the PCB yet, so I do not know if this will work, nor do I want to risk it if it does not, so any help from more experienced people would be appreciated. The picture below shows my problem.

Comment: Please add some screenshots of the issue.

Comment: Are the pads part of different nets?

Comment: Do you have a schematic showing the desired connections?  The Design Rule Check feature will prevent you from making connections that don't agree with the schematic.

Comment: Do I need to make nets between the same pins in the schematic to route them in pcbnew?

Comment: You may be able to turn off DRC in the PC layout program - then you could connect things without reference to a schematic (or in violation of the schematic).  However, best practice is to draw a schematic which shows all components and required connections, then KiCAD will guide you in making the required connections on the PC board with the DRC function preventing incorrect connections.

Comment: I will wire it on the schematic, thank you for the help.

Comment: Was your Net list properly loaded to the PCB tool? After loading the Net names will show up in small text within each pad. If a trace does not connect check the net names of the pads you are connecting. Did you make changes after some routing, there is a chance that small segments remain (unseen) within a pad, if the segments are of a different Net that too could prevent a later connection. (Try deleting any segments pieces at the center of a pad if you suspect that). If for some reason you absolutely had to make a new connection you could edit the parameters of a pad (including its Net name).

Comment: Please show the corresponding part of the schematic.

Comment: Thank you, it works now, the parts were from different nets so they were not able to be routed with each other, but I cut and pasted them to the PCB so they can be routed now.